# Get-Content dumping info from text file into an attribute

Tags: powershell-3.0, dhcp

So I'm running into this problem where I'm trying to insert IPs from a text file into an attribute.

Here is my code:

```bsh
$scope = Get-Content C:\scripts\scopeadd\scopes.txt 
Get-DhcpServerv4Policy -ScopeId $scope
```

I think i might need to use a `Get-Content`/`ForEach-Object` combination but haven't been able to lock it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have several scopes in your file and want to run `Get-DhcpServerv4Policy` for each scope you can use `ForEach-Object` like this:

```bsh
Get-Content 'C:\scripts\scopeadd\scopes.txt' | ForEach-Object {
  Get-DhcpServerv4Policy -ScopeId $_
}
```

You could also use a `foreach` loop like this:

```bsh
$scopes = Get-Content 'C:\scripts\scopeadd\scopes.txt'
foreach ($scope in $scopes) {
  Get-DhcpServerv4Policy -ScopeId $scope
}
```